# How to get a global value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know what is the difference between `$(function(){}` and a `onlick function showDetail(){}`
Why the first function can get a global value but the second can't get the value?

```
"<td>" +"<a onclick=showDetail(" + val.id + "," + item_skus_id +")>DETAIL</a> " + "</td>" +

<script>
$(function(){
    // a global item_skus_id here can be gotten 
}
function showDetail(radio_id, item_skus_id) {
    //the global item_skus_id value can't be gotten here why?
}
</script>
```

Comment: how are you saying `item_skus_id` is global in `$(function(){})`

Comment: what does "can't get a value" actually mean?  is it just undefined?  are you sure it is being set?  where are you closing the open parenthesis for `$(function(){`?

Comment: what you are asking is javascript 101 ....read up on `scope` and `closures`. This is just not the place for asking trivial questions like yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get value of global variable `item_skus_id` inside `showDetail` function, you may want to use `window.item_skus_id`. That's because you declared a parameter with the same name in `showDetail` function - and it masks the global variable. So when you write `item_skus_id` you refer to the parameter.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)